# Getting the original class's member

Tags: python

I'm writing a game where things may be modified by special effects. I've decided to use python's ability to assign to an instance, rather than the class. Note that this is **NOT** modifying the entire class' member, just one instance of it. Think of it as a local enchantment in MtG.

How do I get back to the original class's member?

Take the following example code:

```
class Dog(object):
    noise = "Woof!"

    def bark(self):
        print self.noise

    def make_alpha(self):
        self.noise = self.noise.upper()

class Bulldog(Dog):
    noise = "Grr!"

class EnormousBulldog(Bulldog):
    pass

puppy = Dog()
print puppy.bark() # Woof!
bulldog = Bulldog()
print bulldog.bark() #Grr!
big_dog = EnormousBulldog()
print big_dog.bark() # Grr!

big_dog.make_alpha()
print puppy.bark() # Woof!
print bulldog.bark() # Grr!
print big_dog.bark() # GRR!
```

This all works.

But suppose I want to make a remove_alpha() method. I could try to reverse the effects of make_alpha() on the noise (and therefore do this for every possible special effect in the actual game), but I sense down that road lies madness. Simpler would be to just get back to Bulldog.noise. But how does EnormousBulldog get to Bulldog.noise?

`self.__dict__["noise"]` will give me the modified noise.

`EnormousBulldog.__dict__` will give me nothing, because noise is in Bulldog, its superclass.

`type(self).__getattribute__(self, "noise")` will see there's a modified noise, and give me that instead.

I've considered overriding `__getattribute__` instead of altering the instances as an alternate architecture entirely, but I think the performance hit isn't worth it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The superclass variable is always available as `self.__class__.noise` or `EnormousBulldog.noise`, or `getattr(self.__class__, 'noise')`.

Or if your question is "how do you cancel the per-instance changes", then `del` the attribute from the instance, possibly with a guard:

```
def remove_alpha(self):
    if 'noise' in self.__dict__:
        del self.noise
```

After that the attribute lookup would find it in the superclass.

---

And no, do not confuse `__getattr__` with `__getattribute__`; you want to override the former `__getattr__`; the latter is almost certainly never what you want to do.

Comment: I was most certainly considering `__getattribute__` and not `__getattr__`, because the calls I might be intercepting were overwriting things that already existed. I.e. overwriting a Creature's .turn() to have something happen before/after its turn. `__getattr__` only works for things that are not found, no?

Comment: It is true. But after that you cannot do anything anymore, since all access to the instance's object properties will trigger a call to `__getattribute__`.

Answer (score 1):

There's a quite dirty and confusing solution, but that will probably do what you want: It relies on the fact that *instance* attributes are evaluated before *class* attributes:

```
class Dog(object):
    noise = "Woof!"

    def bark(self):
        print self.noise

    def make_alpha(self):
        self.noise = self.__class__.noise.upper()

    def remove_alpha(self):
        try:
            del self.noise
        except AttributeError:
            print ("You tried to call remove_alpha into an"
                   " instance that doesn't have its own noise!!")

class Bulldog(Dog):
    noise = "Grr!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bulldog = Bulldog()
    bulldog.bark()
    print "Checkpoint: noise is NOT among the instance's vars: %s" % vars(bulldog)
    bulldog.make_alpha()
    print "Checkpoint: now noise is among the instance's vars: %s" % vars(bulldog)
    bulldog.bark()
    bulldog.remove_alpha()
    print "Checkpoint: noise is NOT among the instance's vars: %s" % vars(bulldog)
    bulldog.bark()

    print "Second test:"
    bulldog02 = Bulldog()
    bulldog02.bark()
    print "Checkpoint: noise is NOT among the instance's vars: %s" % vars(bulldog)
    bulldog02.remove_alpha()
    print "Checkpoint: noise is NOT among the instance's vars: %s" % vars(bulldog)
    bulldog02.bark()
```

Which outputs:

```
Grr!
Checkpoint: noise is NOT among the instance's vars: {}
Checkpoint: now noise is among the instance's vars: {'noise': 'GRR!'}
GRR!
Checkpoint: noise is NOT among the instance's vars: {}
Grr!
Second test:
Grr!
Checkpoint: noise is NOT among the instance's vars: {}
You tried to call remove_alpha into an instance that doesn't have its own noise!!
Checkpoint: noise is NOT among the instance's vars: {}
Grr!
```

What's happening is that when you call `make_alpha`, a new `noise` attribute is added to the *instance*, which supersedes the `noise` attribute on the *class* level. You may want to check what the built-in [vars](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) does.

Comment: I was using the instance-over-class feature already, I was just trying to find a way to get it to stop.

Comment: Oh... Wooop, wooop... Meeeeh... So... I did reply to your question... and more because of my lack of understanding... **:-D**  Yep... @AnttiHappala's answer is much more concise... Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest a different approach, which has some performance impact, but keeps the code a bit simpler and way more flexible:

```
class EnhancedAction(object):
    """
    A way to keep track of the enhanced implementation,
    as well as the original one, to allow to go back to it
    """

    def __init__(self, target, original, impl):
        self._target = target
        self._original = original
        self._impl = impl

    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self._impl(self._target, self._original, args)

    @property
    def original(self):
        return self._original


class Dog(object):
    noise = "Woof!"

    def bark(self):
        return self.noise

    def make_alpha(self):
        self.bark = EnhancedAction(
            target=self, original=self.bark,
            impl=lambda self, original, args: original().upper()
    )

    def revert_alpha(self):
        if isinstance(self.bark, EnhancedAction):
            self.bark = self.bark.original


class Bulldog(Dog):
    noise = "Grr!"


class EnormousBulldog(Bulldog):
    pass


big_dog = EnormousBulldog()
print "Regular bark:", big_dog.bark()  # Grr!
big_dog.make_alpha()
print "Enhanced bark:", big_dog.bark()  # GRR!
big_dog.revert_alpha()
print "Back to regular:", big_dog.bark()  # Grr!
```

**Cons**:

- Yet another level of indirection (performance hit)

**Pros**:

- You can call the original implementation from the enhanced one
- You can composed enhanced actions